# What postgres datatype to use for storing small integer values

Tags: postgresql

What postgres datatype to use for storing small integer values (say from 1-10 or from 1-32 max). Should it be int2 or is there anything smaller?

Comment: What's wrong with [smallint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data type `"char"`. It is described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html):

> The type `"char"` (note the quotes) is different from `char(1)` in that it only uses one byte of storage. It is internally used in the system catalogs as a simplistic enumeration type.

Note that you have to align columns carefully if you want to take advantage of that.

For example, an `integer` always starts at an offset that is a multiple of four. If we take the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   small "char" NOT NULL,
   other integer NOT NULL
);
```

Then each row will occupy 8 bytes (apart from the column header): 1 byte for `small`, three “padding bytes”, four bytes for `other`.

Very often, trying to scrape out a few bytes from storage is not worth the effort.